# window.location - how to open a blank window

Tags: javascript

I have a login script and currently when all is done the client is redirected to the billing page.

I'd like this page to open in a new browser window not the existing one as the current code does.

```
function go_to_private_pageb() {
    window.location = '../########/billing.php'; // Members Area
}
```

Comment: `window.open(URL,name,specs,replace)`

Comment: This has nothing to do with jquery please change the title.

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
function opentab(url) {
    window.open(url, '_blank');
}
```

"opentab" suggests that it's always a tab, which is opened and not a window. This doesn't have to be the case, but since modern browsers use tabs, it is most common.

However, there is no way to control the result.

Comment: you may want to call the function something else because opentab suggests that a new tab will be open and the author wants a new window. Plus, as I said, you can't really control the result

Answer (score 2):

below command will be useful for u.

```
window.open("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
```

Answer (score 1):

have a look at `window.open()`. More [here](http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml), for example. 
Note that the browser may be configured not to allow pop-up windows and the page may end up being displayed in another tab. There is nothing to do about that.

Answer (score 1):

window.open(URL,name,specs,replace)

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Comment: I've always trusted w3schools, not once have they lead me astray. A big resource like that is bound to have it's flaws here and there but I don't think that justifies blacklisting the entire site.

Comment: I have NEVER trusted w3schools - 80% of the times I looked, their data was outdated or plain wrong when it comes to JavaScript. I only ever use them for a quick reminder of a CSS attribute but take anything they write with scepticism

Comment: A case in point. Example 2 on the link you gave does not do a MANDATORY `myWindow.document.close()` that will give VERY weird results in almost all browsers - gecko based browsers will keep showing the loading... and you cannot print the content in some browsers. Typically w3schools. Thousands of beginning javascripters will see this code and use it...

Answer (score 1):

Umm. `window.open()` will open a new **tab** if not provided any `spec` parameter.

```
window.open('http://google.com', '', 'width=<anything>');
```

This will open a new window, but won't have the tabs.